# Unexpected Output from Python Script

Tags: python, integer, conditional-statements

I am hoping someone can help resolve an unexpected output issue I am having with a Python script.

I seem to be having trouble getting "if-elif" conditional statements to work correctly with integer ranges 64 - 69 and 72 - 77, respectively.

The object of the very simple script below is to convert a student's numerical exam score into a matching letter grade, on the standard scale of A, B, C, D, or F:

```
num_grade = 85

if num_grade >= 90 | num_grade <= 100:
    print("The student has a letter grade of A")

elif num_grade >= 80 | num_grade <= 89:
    print("The student has a letter grade of B")

elif num_grade >= 70 | num_grade <= 79:
    print("The student has a letter grade of C")

elif num_grade >= 60 | num_grade <= 69:
    print("The student has a letter grade of D")

elif num_grade >= 0 | <= 59:
    print("The student has a letter grade of F")

print (num_grade)  # This confirms the actual value stored in num_grade.

print (type(num_grade))  # A test of the data type that should be stored in num_grade.
```

Here is the sample output that I expect to receive from the script, as typed:

```
The student has a letter grade of B
85
<class 'int'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I store integers 64 - 69, or 72 - 77 in num_grade, the output I get is different than shown in my first example, above:

```
num_grade = 74  # Only the integer ranges 64 - 69 and 72 - 77 generate the "unexpected" output.
```

Output Below:

```
74
<class 'int'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The actual "Letter Grade" string is omitted from output.  I see only the value stored in num_grade, as well as the data type.  I manually tested all values 0 - 100.

Does anyone have an explanation for what is causing this output?  There do not seem to be any obvious errors in my syntax, such as mismatched operators in the "if-elif" statements.  I have run the script using the latest versions of PyCharm, Jupyter Notebook, and Python terminal and get the same results.

My computer is a newer-model PC with Windows 10 Professional version 2004.

Comment: Do you prefer more Pythonic way to solve this problem, or insist the current one?

Comment: Also it should be and since you are trying to fit into disjoint intervals and if you need & make sure you use brackets

Comment: Generally, with python, you use logical operators like _or_ instead of |, or _and_ instead of &. For example, the beginning of your if statement, `if num_grade >= 90 | num_grade <= 100`, can correctly be converted to  `if num_grade >= 90 or num_grade <= 100`. Also, since you are checking to see if a variable is within a certain range, `if 90 <= num_grade <= 100:` would work better for your purposes

Comment: The pipe is a bitwise OR of integers operator in python. Also, using OR conditions for this logic flow, I would think that all letter grades would trigger `"The student has a letter grade of C"` condition, given that any letter grade from 0-100 would satisfy the `num_grade <= 100` condition. Logically I think you would want to use `and` instead, or just use the first condition in each `if`/`elif` statement.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks everyone for your help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test whether the number is in range you would need to change the operator and use the `and`, you are using the binary condition operator or(`|`).

Below is the code that I believe you are trying to create:

```
num_grade = 74


if num_grade >= 90 and num_grade <= 100:
    # if the number is greater than or equal to 90 and less than or equal to 100 do this
    # do not use the 'or' operator as the number, 
    # although not greater than or equal to 90, is less than or equal to 100
    print("The student has a letter grade of A")
elif num_grade >= 80 and num_grade <= 89:
    print("The student has a letter grade of B")
elif num_grade >= 70 and num_grade <= 79:
    print("The student has a letter grade of C")
elif num_grade >= 60 and num_grade <= 69:
    print("The student has a letter grade of D")
elif num_grade >= 0 and num_grade <= 59:
    print("The student has a letter grade of F")
print (num_grade)  # This confirms the actual value stored in num_grade.

print (type(num_grade))  # A test of t
```